# How do the major OS like Windows, Mac and Ubuntu/Redhat handle DST and time that goes back 1+ hour?

Tags: operating-systems, time, date-time, ntp, time-zone

When time is out of sync, I understand most of the modern operating systems have NTP software that do it in smart increments spreading it through a large interval such that it doesn't affect most software.

However, I fail to understand how this is done for regions that turn back time 1 hour - the internal details of how this actually happens. As engineers, we use UTC to make sure we're abstracted away from these problems, and programs just interpret the UTC time which is one-directional flow, but it's not uncommon for  programs to deal with local time in many cases, for example, logs in local time etc.

How does DST turning back 1 hour, etc exactly work internally on the major OSes and their distributions? I'm looking for specifics - for example, let's say  London turns back the clock from 2:00am to 1:00am on October 25th. Some time zones also provide information such that between when this has to be spread out. What exactly does all these entail under the covers?

(Context: I come from a tz where a fixed offset is followed throughout the year, so my understanding of this is a bit limited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does an internal clock knows when we go back one hour, that it is in the new daylight savings, and not repeat itself over and over?

When you see time on your computer, it is the outcome of a series of calculations. In reality, time is measured in seconds from a point in the past and what point that it is different per device, but this time does not change when we alter timezones or daylight saving. On a PC, this is stored in the BIOS or UEFI. This is actually why we had a big problem in the year 2000, but that's another story.

So, every device that has an internal clock, knows the current time because it knows how much time has elapsed in seconds from its starting time.

In essence, the device has a battery and a program running that keeps adding one second to the elapsed time since the starting point.

When you talk about formatting time, you have to deal with timezones and daylight savings.

The timezone alters the clock in hours based on what the timezone is set to. If you are in UTC+3, the time is calculated as follows:

```
start time -> elapsed time in seconds converted to years, months, days, hours, seconds. 
  \-> Add 3 hours
       \-> new time is correct time and date for UTC+3
```

When daylight savings goes into effect, the time becomes time + UTC+3 +DST+1

```
start time -> elapsed time in seconds converted to years, months, days, hours, seconds. 
  \-> Add 3 hours
       \-> Add 1 hour for Daylight saving
           \-> new time is correct time and date for UTC+3 +DST+1
```

This means, that aside from 3 hours being added for the timezone, an additional hour is being added for the daylight saving.

When we move back to winter time, or DST+0, the next time the date and time are calculated, it automatically jumps back one hour.

As you can see, the base timer that counts never changes.

If you alter the date/time on your computer, it basically calculates how many seconds have passed, keeping in mind the timezone and daylight saving setting, and then changes the new difference from the starting point as the new "how much seconds have passed since" timer, and such, your time is displayed correctly.

Comment: Thank you @LPChip for the detailed answer :) - however, I'm trying to understand a bit more on what happens during the DST change when RTC clock is set to local. For instance, while Linux uses UTC, Windows default to local RTC. Now when there's a DST, doesn't this affect the whole system internally? 

How is all this handled?

Comment: @70766c The internal clock is never altered on a DST change, only the "Are we in DST mode right now" adjustment setting is altered and the displayed time changes when it recalculates the time. Keep in mind, the whole DST thing existed before the first personal computer was created. It was baked in from the start.

Comment: @70766c Glad I could help. :)

Comment: epoch of 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970, which explains why if there is a calculation error I have files with dates saying 1969!!!

Comment: @UbuntuForums_Staff_Are_Trolls linux epoch indeed uses januari 1st, 1970. But this date is not always the same for computers or other devices. Basically, reset your BIOS to factory defaults and look at the time/date presented. Usually somewhere close to the manufacturer date, that is the time of which the device calculates its time.

Comment: I get files on Windows with 1969 as the date, maybe because they were transferred from Linux?

Comment: @UbuntuForums_Staff_Are_Trolls filedates have nothing to do with the time displayed on the computer clock. Its calculated in the same way, but is not part of the answer for this question. But yes, linux epoch is 0:00 @ jan 1st, 1970. If your timezone settings are UTC -3 for example and the file has no creation date set, then indeed, you get 1969 as date.

Comment: Yes I was saying it's approx the same date because it's calculated the same

Answer (score 1):

On a linux systems , informations about timezones info are provide by `tzdata` .

The official source is : 
https://www.iana.org/time-zones

More informations :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database